# Can you have a Sequence of case objects in Scala?

Tags: scala

Can you have a Seq of type of a case object in Scala?

i.e.

```
case object SuccessResult

case class Results(successes: Seq[SuccessResult])
```

(IntelliJ is showing SuccessResult as red)

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to open a REPL and try it instead of asking a question?

Comment: Yes, I then went on to do this. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can test it easily in basic Scala REPL or Ammonite (I prefer the later):

```
@ case object A
defined object A

@ Seq(A, A, A)
res14: Seq[A.type] = List(A, A, A)
```

type inference make it work with sealed hierarchies of case objects as well (basically enums):

```
@ {
  sealed trait Foo
  case object Bar extends Foo
  case object Baz extends Foo
  }
defined trait Foo
defined object Bar
defined object Baz

@ Seq(Bar, Bar, Baz, Baz, Bar, Baz)
res16: Seq[Product with Foo with Serializable] = List(Bar, Bar, Baz, Baz, Bar, Baz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes We can do this, just need to keep one Parent type to resolve the child

```
sealed trait Parent
case object Child extends Parent
case object Child1 extends Parent
case object Child2 extends Parent

Seq(Child,Child1,Child2)

Seq[Product with Serializable with Parent] = List(Child, Child1, Child2)
```